# Phil Sturgeon with API Key, what is the best approach?

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I try to use the excellent work of Phil Sturgeon (Codeigniter RestServer) for my service.

I plan to use this workflow:

```
client --> client connect to my service with credentials 
server <-- check credentials in db, generate api-key for this user, and send it
client --> send request to get personal infos with new api-key in header
server <-- retrieve infos for this user from api-key, send infos
client --> another request with new api-key in header
server <-- check if api-key lifetime < 15m, if ok execute request and update lifetime else return timeout error
...
```

Anyone can help me to do this using RestServer X-API-KEY, or I can just make my own API-KEY management ?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I need to know if I can do that with Phil sturgeon's RestServer implementation or if I plan to do my own key management  (for lifetime). With Phil Sturgeon's implementation, how I can assign key to account? how can I check lifetime of key before server allow access? And Is my workflow the best solution ? Thanks. The lifetime of api key is for prevent network sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this with the X-API-KEY used in the Library. The usage of the key is to authenticate apps that you have whitelisted to access your API.

In your case, what you want to do is get your app to generate an auth token and return that to the client. The client should then use the auth token to make requests.

The X-API-KEY should be used to verify that the request is coming from a whitelisted "client". Here's what the flow would look like:

**client** --> client connect to your service with credentials and x-api-key
**server** <-- verifies **x-api-key**, check credentials against db, generate auth token for this user, and sends it back in a response
**client** --> send request to get personal infos with auth token
**server** <-- checks validity of auth token, retrieve infos for this user and returns response
**client** --> another request with auth token
**server** <-- check if auth token is still valid (check expiry time, etc) and return response